# AWS VPC custom VIP: How to get a IP Address assumption to work across two EC2 VPC instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, heartbeat, pacemaker, amazon-vpc

I created an AWS VPC and three instances therein (*head*, *nodeA*, and *nodeB*).  I also associated them all with a security group that allows fully open networking among the private (RFC-1918) addresses within my VPC block.  In other words any of these three source address can touch any TCP or UDP port or use any ICMP protocol to any of the other addresses within the VPC netblock (10.x.0.0/16).

Networking among the three instances is working.  Names are propated into /etc/hosts on each instance and those are working.

Now I want to use another address (10.x.0.100) as a custom VIP within that block, assigning it as an IP alias (eth0:0) to nodeA, running a service on that, then model breaking the service in various way and having nodeB take over that VIP (using tools like [heartbeat](http://linux-ha.org/wiki/Heartbeat) and [pacemaker](http://linux-ha.org/wiki/Pacemaker).

I written a one-line `takevip` shell script which simply does `ifconfig eth0:0 10.X.0.100 ...` and executed it on nodeA (and ONLY one nodeA).

That's where I'm stuck.  How do I register this address as in use within my virtual network segment?

I've tried `ping -I`10.x.0.100 10.x.0.1` (pinging the virtual router with my VIP as the source).  That gets 100% packet loss.  (Pinging .0.1 from all other instances works fine, as expected).

I've double and triple checked that my interface configuration (`ifconfig -a`) on nodeA is correct and that there's no conflict on nodeB (yet).

Comment: I have no experience with Amazon's offerings, but a quick web search found [Leveraging Multiple IP Addresses for Virtual IP Address Fail-over in 6 Simple Steps](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/2127188135977316).

Comment: @yoonix you nailed it with that link.